# fetching API with angular

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, api, express

hi I have a RestFul API BackEnd with Nodejs and ExpressJS framework and also my FrontEnd framework is Angular so when I call any API in PostMan application, everything is fine and I can fetch correctly response, and also I ok by calling APIs in browser **but** when that API calls with **Angular** I cant send request and so I cant fetch any data from the server, so why I can send a request and receive a response from RestFul API in PostMan and browser but in the angular project it's not working correctly and debugger of angular don't work!

```
const url = 'http://111.222.333.444:8080/api/v1/admin/login';

    const body = {
      email: 'myname@gmail.com',
      password: '123456'
    };

    this.http.post(url, body).subscribe(
      res => {
        debugger;
        //TODO
      },
      error => {
        //TODO
      }
    );
```

Comment: What are you doing in Angular? Show some code.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem, this problem was from backend because I don't add response header: Cross-origin resource sharing (cors policy) to responses and when I added this now I can fetch the response from server.

-everyone has this problem can see this document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS